# How can I accept string inputs of undetermined size?

Tags: c, string

So a bit of python vs C here.

I just wrote a program in python to do calculations and the function accepts all numbers as string inputs so that that can handle incredibly huge numbers.

Is there anyway to do this in C without specifying an exact limit to the string length?

So I have a string limit of 100 characters atm in the following base converter function. (Currently only converts to base 10)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <math.h>

char SYMBOLS[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

//just testing how to access the SYMBOLS[]
int print_symbols() {


    printf("Printing individual characters at a time:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(SYMBOLS); i++)
    {
        printf("%c ",SYMBOLS[i]);
    }
    printf("\nLength/num of symbols: %d", strlen(SYMBOLS));

    printf("\n\nPrinting the whole string at once:\n");
    printf("%s", SYMBOLS);
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}

//accepts a string to display a prompt to the user and returns input
char* input(char prompt[]) {
    static char received[100];
    printf("%s", prompt);
    fgets(received,100,stdin);
    //Find the return charage and replace with string terminator
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(received); i++)
    {
        if (received[i] == '\n') {
            received[i] = '\0';
        }
    }

    return received;
}

char* reverse(char string[]) {
    static char reversed[100];
    int len = strlen(string);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        reversed[len - 1 - i] = string[i];
    }
    return reversed;
}

char* from_base_10(char num[], int base) {
    //NOTE: this function isnt finished and is not actually use yet....
    static char new_num[100];
    int numInt = atoi(num);
    int div;
    int rem;
    int count=0;

    if (base>36)
    {
        strcpy(new_num,"\nERROR: Base can not be higher than 36\n");
        return new_num;
    }

    while (numInt>0)
    {
        div = numInt / base;
        rem = numInt % base;
        //printf("%d \\ %d = %d remainder %d symbol = %c\n",numInt, base, div, rem, SYMBOLS[rem]);

        //can not use strcpy or strcat as a single char has no '\0' terminator
        new_num[count] = SYMBOLS[rem];

        count++;
        numInt = div;
    }
    new_num[count] = '\0';//finish the new string off

    //and now the new string has to be reversed
    strcpy(new_num, reverse(new_num));

    return new_num;
}

char* to_base_10(char num[], int base) {
    static char new_num[100];
    int len = strlen(num);
    int power;
    int total=0;
    char digit[2];//to use atoi() on a single char we still need a '\0' so didgit needs to be a 2 char string

    if (base > 36)
    {
        strcpy(new_num, "ERROR: Base can not be higher than 36.");
        return new_num;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        power = len - 1 - i;
        digit[0] = num[i];
        //add digit times base to the power of its position in the number
        total += atoi(digit) * pow((double)base, (double)power);
    }
    printf("\n New Number is : %d\n", total);

    itoa(total, new_num, 10); //LOL and at this point I findout this function actually converts base at the same time.
    return new_num;
}


int main() {
    char* result;//accapts strings from input()
    result = "";//needs a value for strcmp to use it

    while (strcmp(result, "exit")!=0)
    {
        printf("\n\n\n Brads Math Functions \n");
        printf("======================\n");
        printf("Enter [exit] to quit.\n");
        printf("Enter [base] to convert numbers from one base to another.\n");
        result = input("\nEnter an option from the menu:");

        if (strcmp(result,"base")==0)
        {
            char num[100];
            strcpy(num, result=input("Enter a number:"));
            int end = atoi( input("Enter base:"));
            printf("\nResult: %s\n", to_base_10(num, end));
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Python does not accept unlimited size strings. No existing computer can.

Comment: You can have that much big array with automatic storage .Program will crash on first second .

Comment: Ohhh one more question - **Why** do you need this much big space ?

Comment: Have you got infinite amounts of memory? No. Therefore, an infinite string is impossible, even on the largest supercomputers.

Comment: address space is limited (usually 32 or 64bit), memory is limited, ... you can not have a number or string of unlimited size. please tell us what exactly you want to do, and optimally show the code you already have, and we may be able to help you with your practical problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, no existing computer will allow you to store "unlimited" values. In fact, taking in consideration that the current universe may be finite, there is no way to do that in our reality.

However, if you want to store "large" numbers ( "large" meaning numbers that surpass any existing number data type in C ), you might want to consider storing them as char arrays. Again, you'd be limited with virtual address space your application has been given ( see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) ).

You might want to take a look at [Dynamic Memory Allocation in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), which might help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

To accept string inputs of "unlimited" size:

[`getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), not standard, but often in *nix. It will re-allocate memory as needed.  Sample [source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cvs/cvs-19/cvs/lib/getline.c)

Or write a helper function about `fgets/fgetc` reallocating memory as needed.  Sample [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23178265/2410359)

---

Consider caution in using a function that *accept string inputs of "unlimited" size*.  Fundamentally that is a future security exploit as code is giving control to external data or user to overwhelm resources.

Instead recommend limiting, but to a large value, string input.

```
#define N 1000000
char *ptr = malloc(N);
assert(ptr);
fgets(p, N, stdin);
...
free(ptr);
```

Note: many implementations of C memory allocation functions only allocate, not "use" memory until required.  So a large allocation does not use up memory if not fully needed.